# How to count number of subarrays of one specific subarray?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have loop that is saving data into multidimensional array.

```
$array = array();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    for($j=0;$j<100;$j++) {
        if ($value1 != 0) {
            $array[$i][$j]['key1'] = $value1;
            $array[$i][$j]['key2'] = $value2;
            $array[$i][$j]['key3'] = $value3;
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes there may be no values to save for specific $j key, so before listing I would like to count the number of $j keys of each $i key.

I was trying do that in loop like that but it's not working:

```
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    if (count($array[$i]) > 0) {
        for($j=0;$j<count($array[$i]);$j++) {
            echo $array[$i][$j]['key1'];
            echo $array[$i][$j]['key2'];
            echo $array[$i][$j]['key3'];;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've seen many topics about counting arrays, but nothing similar to my problem.
Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
As I looked into the comments I realized myself that indeed I've made mistake in the question, this is because I was writing the post very late, after many hours of work. Sorry.

The proper array reading code (that is representing my need) is:

```
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
    if (count($array[$i]) > 0) {
        echo "table header";
    }
    for($j=0;$j<count($array[$i]);$j++) {
        echo $array[$i][$j]['key1'];
        echo $array[$i][$j]['key2'];
        echo $array[$i][$j]['key3'];
    }
}
```

As you see now I need to know if there are any data for each $i because table header is to be generated (or not) according to that.

Comment: why the need to count when ur problem is `there may be no values to save` ?

Comment: I don't understand your  code that creates the arrays. It's using the same values in every element.

Comment: You don't need the `if` statement. If the count is 0, the nested loop won't do anything.

Comment: I strongly recommend you learn to use `foreach` when looping over arrays.

Comment: I know how to use foreach - in here it'd not the case - it looked it was, but this is because of my mistake of representing the problem.
I also need If statement as I need to know before loop starts to know if there are any data to read.
Others: Presented model is made up and simplified as possible to present main problem. Please don't bother the if there is loop or not. I just need to count $j keys of specific $i key ...